# Apache Beam For Real Time ETL

Tags: mysql, performance, parallel-processing, apache-beam

I working on an application which is supposed to **read the data(json) from a particular source, do the business required transformation on it and then load it to MySQL database in real time** (time duration for all this should be in milliseconds).

Till now I have been able to do this using **Apache Beam with spark runner and Java**, but it takes more time as compared to what the expectation is (approx. 25 secs for close to 2 million records).
I am very new to Apache Beam and I would like to know if there is something that I can do to improve the performance of the application or should I move to some other Tech stack that would help me to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using the JDBCIO and running a streaming pipeline?

Comment: I earlier used JDBCIO to write the the transformed PCollection directly to mysql but it was again taking huge amount of time as well as due to a large number of connections (connection per element) to the database, the db itself was not functioning properly. So I shifted to TEXTIO to first write the data to files and then load the files using "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" to mysql.

Answer (score 0):

When speed is the main criteria, you need to understand the SQL that is being generated by the intermediate package(s).

The layers (beam/runner/java/etc) are handy to make the logic a little simpler.  But you cannot necessarily trust them to generate optimal SQL.

Plan A:  Provide the generated SQL for critique.

Plan B:  Jetisson the layers and use SQL directly.  (There would, of course, be a *simple* API that would clearly expose what the generated SQL will be.)

As a general rule with SQL, it is better to operate on hundreds of thousands of rows in a single query.  Using a loop to issue hundreds or thousands of one-row SQL statements is likely to be literally 10 times as slow.

That *may* involve loading all the data *unmodified* into a table, then doing the ETL in SQL -- operating on one 'column' at a time instead of one 'row' at a time.  Show us one JSON string together with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and explain the "T" (transformation) of your ETL.

Comment: ETL is handled by apache beam itself and it does that using a multithreaded model. I created a beam pipeline which reads the data from the json file from the source and does the transformations to it and writes the transformed data(again in json format) to multiple files(automatically created by beam). I tried to look if it generates any SQL but couldn't find. After this I create a connection to amazon rds and load these files directly mysql using **"load data local infile 'file_path' into table rdstest.sample LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'"** in a loop.

Comment: @ShubhamTomar - `LOAD DATA` is very efficient in MySQL.  Can you tell how long the `LOAD` took versus the transform time?

Comment: For approximately 1.4 million records(179 MB) the transformation takes 13 seconds and loading of transformed 1.4 million records(68 MB) takes 74 seconds. After transformation the output comes in usually 4 files, after that I use LOAD DATA with executeUpdate in a loop.

Comment: @ShubhamTomar - Does "loading" consist of 4 `LOAD DATA` calls in parallel, plus the `executeUpdate`?  I expect the `LOAD` to be fast; can you split the two steps apart to get timing of each?  And, what is "executeUpdate"?  (I am not familiar with Beam.)  If the "loop" is 1.4M `UPDATEs`, then we need to focus on that.

Comment: Yes the LOAD DATA calls are run in parallel, The executeUpdate is a way to run SQL queries using JAVA, I am using it to run the load data calls. `statement.execute("load data CONCURRENT local infile \"" + filePath + "\" into table testdb.sample LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'");`

Comment: `LOAD DATA` is an efficient, intense, statement.  I suspect that 4 copies might not run much faster in parallel than serially.  (I realize that this does not answer your Question.)